# How to make a button responsive and centered?

Tags: css, width, block

I want to make a button centered and responsive. But I can't give it a width otherwise the background color goes with it. any solutions?

Code:

```
  background-color: #03326c;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 530px;
  margin-top: -70px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 180px;
  z-index: 100000;
}

<div class="product-button1"><a href="http://blabla.com/blabla.html" title="reserveren"><span class="reserverenButton1">Reserveer hier</span></a></div>
```

Comment: We'd need to see the actual HTML & CSS involved...can you make a demo? That giant margin has me worried.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Don't mind the margins. I'm making a adbanner from HTML/CSS. It's very tricky to make through floats and all that. This works fine in combination with media queries. The HTML is edited in my OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear exactly how this will look and we have limited information based on your code but this will work.

It's not clear what you mean by the button being "responsive" but it is centered and no width has been defined.

```css
.product-button1 {
  text-align: center;
}
product-button1 a {
  background-color: #03326c;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 35px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  padding: .5em 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-button1">
  <a href="http://blabla.com/blabla.html" title="reserveren"><span class="reserverenButton1">Reserveer hier</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I meant. However I can't edit the A tags because of the template I'm using. So I geuss I have to put them all in the productbutton1 and the text align in the span class reserverenbutton1? Also, I have a limited space of 300px on the left hand side of the website. It needs to be centered there, not responsive, sorry I meant only centered.

Comment: Nope...text aligning the span won't align the button, just the text in the span.

Comment: You really need to show the code you're trying to affect instead of feeding conditions to us piecemeal.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't really share the code for some reason. But here is a tinypic url to the situation. In the picture you can see a picture in a space of 250ish px width but it has to be centered in that space only. Same for the button. Your code works fine when it uses 100% width. So you don't need to set any width but in media query it only has a width of 85%. http://i61.tinypic.com/zldgyx.png

Comment: Is making a background div with a width of 85% and then using center align css on the productbutton1 the solution?

Comment: I really can't add much more...as I said, without some example code that replicates the **actual** problem it's hard to help. No need for confidential data, just basic layout and dummy content is fine.